# Convert French date string to English date for comparison

Tags: php

I'm running a multi-lingual WordPress site and I need to compare a meta value from a custom post type to the current date.

In English, it's fairly straight forward as I compared the user-entered `start_date` with the system time like so:

```
$postStartDate = strtotime(get_field('start_date'));
$currDate = strtotime(date('F j, Y'));

if ($postStartDate > $currDate):
  // Show the post
endif;
```

I can't use the built-in Published date from WordPress because my client sets up posts far in advance and they should be live until the meta `start_date` is past.

When I try and run something similar with French, however, it fails and that's because `strtotime()` expects English. Fair. So, I read a bit about `setlocale()` and `strftime()` and ended up trying things like this:

```
$frenchDate = strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime(get_field('start_date')));
```

Of course, this also fails because `strtotime()` cannot understand 'Janvier' versus 'January', etc. so it's a non-starter right away. `strftime()` just spits out Jan 1, 1970 in this case.

This isn't a French server environment, merely a bilingual site.

What is the best way to compare a French date string to the current system date?

Comment: The best way is to save your date in some sensible format, like, let's say, `n j, Y`, or even better in native date format of your database. As far as I remember, all countries have 12 months in a year. What you're doing is asking for crutches to put your code on. Well, you're on wordpress after all, so it doesn't surprise me.

Comment: Right, that makes sense - abstract the language out of it! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: You should move to something better than wordpress. It's crappy architecture and senseless keyboard beating to produce some code is like cancer, killing any ability to think rationally. Heck, half of the project is still on PHP 4!

Comment: That's a rather useless and elitist comment that unfortunately spoils a rather good point you made about the linguistic and numerical approaches to date-time coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with when the overall site architecture can't be changed was to create an associate array to map French strings back into English for `strtotime()` to understand:

```
var monthMap = {
  'janvier' => 'january',
  ...
}
```

Lowercase your strings then take the French month and replace it with `substr_replace()` to create an English date.

A little hacky? Yes. But in the absence of any other answers, it works (so long as all French months are spelled properly by the inputting user!)